# Keep buttons in fixed position when toggling accordion expand/collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am using two buttons and some jQuery to toggle (expand/collapse) two divs with tables inside them. When I toggle the first div with button 1, button 2 gets pushed down below the div. How could I adjust my code so the buttons will stay in the same position and just toggle the divs below.

Here's a codepen:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EjGrKX

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accordion-toggle" id="btnMatch">
        Matched</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
        <table class="table" id="match-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                      <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                      <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger accordion-toggle" id="btnNoMatch">
        No Match</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
                    <table class="table" id="no-match-table">
            <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test</th>
              <th>Test</th>

            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                      <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                      <td>
                            Test
                        </td>
                    </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#btnMatch {
margin-right: 10px;
}


.accordion-toggle {cursor: pointer;}
.accordion-content {display: none;}
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
$("#accordion").find(".accordion-toggle").click(function () {
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");
    $(".accordion-content").not($(this).next()).slideUp("fast");

});
});
```

If I just put the buttons next to eachother, then button 1 will toggle button 2 instead of the content I would like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you map button to accordion-content div using index, you can keep buttons together in HTML.

**JS**

```
$("#accordion").find(".accordion-toggle").click(function () {
    var selectedAccordion = $(".accordion-content").eq($(this).index());
    selectedAccordion.slideToggle("fast");
    $(".accordion-content").not(selectedAccordion).slideUp("fast");            
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="accordion">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success accordion-toggle" id="btnMatch">
    Matched</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger accordion-toggle" id="btnNoMatch">
    No Match</button>
    <div class="accordion-content">
    <table class="table" id="match-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                  <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                  <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="accordion-content">
                <table class="table" id="no-match-table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>
          <th>Test</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                  <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                  <td>
                        Test
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a few CSS changes to keep the buttons where they are. Looks like it works:

```
button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

#btnNoMatch {
    left: 100px;
}

.accordion-content {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick example.  http://jsfiddle.net/et8mLa0c/

**HTML**

```
<div id="outer_wrapper">
    <div id="buttons_container">
        <a href="javascript:" data-table="table_one" class="toggle_button">Open Table One</a>
        &nbsp;|&nbsp;
        <a href="javascript:" data-table="table_two" class="toggle_button">Open Table Two</a>
    </div>
    <table id="table_one">
        <tr>
            <td>Table One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table One</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table One</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <table id="table_two">
        <tr>
            <td>Table Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table Two</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Table Two</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#buttons_container{
    height:50px;
    position:relative;
}
a.toggle_button{
    text-decoration:none;
}
table{
    left:10px;
    top:50px;
    width:350px;
    display:none;
    position:absolute;
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
table td{
    border:solid 1px #ddd;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $tables = $('table'),
       $btns = $('.toggle_button');

    $btns.click(toggleTable);

    function toggleTable(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        var $target = $(event.target);
        var tableId = $target.data("table");

        $tables.hide();

        $('#' + tableId).show();
    }
});
```